# How to disable screen blanking when external monitor is connected and lid is closed

Tags: monitor

How to not blank the LCD screen when closing the laptop lid and using an external monitor?

I'm using 11.10 Oneiric and I've already tried the dconf lid settings but without luck!

Comment: Here is a related bug on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/1012277
You can mark it as affecting you and follow it, and see if you can give a hand in the comments! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-tweak from the Ubuntu Software Center has options under "Shell" to set what you want to occur when the laptop lid is closed on battery and AC.  Install it, set it, and try it out.  Should work.  "Nothing" and "Interactive" are both options in the drop down menu.  Not sure what "Interactive" means though...

Comment: it works but only if an external monitor is not connected.
I'd like to close the lid when using an external monitor without blanking the screen.

Comment: Did you try the "interactive" option in gnome-tweak?

Comment: Solved using "do nothing" as setting and when the external monitor blanks out closing the lid if I move the mouse the screen comes back :)

Comment: Awesome.  Hope I was of some help.