# Black screen with mouse cursor when connecting to external monitor with lid closed

Tags: suspend, 20.04, external-monitor

I am trying to use my laptop in a **docked mode**, so external monitor, mouse and keyboard with the lid closed. I found this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84099/how-to-disable-screen-blanking-when-external-monitor-is-connected-and-lid-is-clo) but didn't much and was very old and have tried to the following.

In **gnome tweak tool** I've unticked 'suspend when lid is closed'.

and downloaded caffeine gnome extension to try and prevent sleeping etc.

However, I simply get a blank screen with the mouse cursor still working, the laptop does not suspend though.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: also set `HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore` in my login.conf.

Comment: See if this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162870/black-screen-after-i-close-the-lid-and-reopen) answer your question. The line to read `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` ?

Comment: Forgot to say that. I edited the post. But I use hibernate when not in docked mode. So I set the above properties to try to do nothing when in docked mode.

Comment: I have the same problem. Mine is ubuntu 18.04